# Android Flyout Menu not visible

Tags: android, android-listview

I am not able to view the Flyout Menu. When I swipe from left to right it needs to push the ListView to the right and the make Flyout Menu appear but it does not appear.

Can I know the reason ?

The code appears below :

activity_sample.xml

```
<com.sri.vaave2.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="News" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="Jobs" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="Internships" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >

       <!--  <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="Toggle Menu" /> -->

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
</com.sri.vaave2.FlyOutContainer>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.sri.vaave2;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.sri.vaave2.MainActivity;
import com.sri.vaave2.app.AppController;
import com.sri.vaave2.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import com.sri.vaave2.data.FeedItem;
import com.sri.vaave2.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://coherendz.net/vaavefeed1.json";
    FlyOutContainer root;

    Iterator<?> itr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, null);        
        this.setContentView(root);
        root.setOnTouchListener(this);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        feedItems= getData(0);
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.profile) {
        Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActionProfile.class);
        startActivity(p);
        }   
        else if(id== R.id.feed) {

        Intent f = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Feed.class);
        startActivity(f);

        }
        else if (id == R.id.posting){

        Intent po = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Posting.class);
        startActivity(po);  
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void toggleMenu(View v){
        this.root.toggleMenu();
    }

    /**
     * Detects left and right swipes across a view.
     */
    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (distanceX > 0)
                        onSwipeRight();
                    else
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        toggleMenu(v);
        return false;
    }


    private List<FeedItem> getData(int nodeType) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // We first check for cached request
                Cache cache = null;
                cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache(); 
                Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
                String data = null;
                if (entry != null) { 
                    // fetch the data from cache 
                    try { 
                        data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                        try { 
                            parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data)); 
                        } catch (JSONException e) { 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 

                } else { 
                    // making fresh volley request and getting json 
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, 
                            URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { 

                                @Override 
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString()); 
                                    if (response != null) { 
                                        parseJsonFeed(response); 
                                    } 
                                } 
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() { 

                                @Override 
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { 
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage()); 
                                } 
                            }); 

                // Adding request to volley request queue 
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

               }

                return feedItems;
            }          

             /** 
             * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter 
             * */ 
            private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {

                FeedItem item;
                itr = response.keys();
                try 
              {     
                while(itr.hasNext())

                {
                        String key = itr.next().toString();
                        JSONObject entry = response.getJSONObject(key);

                        JSONObject phone = entry.getJSONObject("basic");
                        String name = phone.getString("title");
                        String description = phone.getString("description");
                        int nodetype = phone.getInt("node_type");
                        JSONObject comments = entry.getJSONObject("comments");
                        String comments_count = comments.getString("count");
                        JSONObject like = entry.getJSONObject("likes");
                        String like_count = like.getString("count");
                        String readable_date = phone.getString("readable_date");


                        item = new FeedItem();
                        item.setNode_type(nodetype); 
                        item.setName(String.valueOf(name));               
                        item.setStatus(String.valueOf(description)); 
                        item.setReadable_date(String.valueOf(readable_date));
                        item.setComments_count(String.valueOf(comments_count));
                        item.setLike_count(String.valueOf(like_count));


                        feedItems.add(item);

                    }                

                  } 
                  catch (JSONException e) 
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                  } 
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

The code below :

listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){

```
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
        // Whatever     
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toggleMenu(listView);       
        }
```

});